# Convex hull returning java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException opencv android

Tags: java, android, opencv

Here is my code:

```
public void findHull(){
    int h = 0;
    double area_Hull = 0;
    hullArea = 0;
    List<MatOfInt> hull = new ArrayList<MatOfInt>();
    hull.add(new MatOfInt());

    Imgproc.convexHull(contours2.get(largest_contour_index), hull.get(largest_contour_index));

    Point[] points = new Point[hull.get(largest_contour_index).rows()];

    for(h=0; h < hull.get(largest_contour_index).rows(); h++) {
        int index = (int)hull.get(largest_contour_index).get(h, 0)[0];
        points[h] = new Point(contours2.get(largest_contour_index).get(index, 0)[0],contours2.get(largest_contour_index).get(index, 0)[1]);
    }
    List<Point[]> hullpoints = new ArrayList<Point[]>();
    hullpoints.add(points);

    noOfDent = h;

    List<MatOfPoint> hullmop = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    MatOfPoint mop = new MatOfPoint();
    mop.fromArray(hullpoints.get(0));
    hullmop.add(mop);

    area_Hull = Imgproc.contourArea(hullmop.get(0));

    hullArea = area_Hull;
    MatOfPoint2f Hullpt = new MatOfPoint2f();
    hullmop.get(0).convertTo(Hullpt, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    hullPerimeter=Imgproc.arcLength(Hullpt, false);
}
```

`contours2` is all the contour in the image which was previously retrieve using findcontours.And largest_contour_index is an index for the largest contours. But I am receiving an exception error at:

```
Imgproc.convexHull(contours2.get(largest_contour_index), hull.get(largest_contour_index));
```

Can you tell where the problem?

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: I suggest you to debug it in order to see the size of each collection: `contours2` and `hull`. Because either one or the other (or even both) don't have `largest_contour_index` elements.

Comment: i find the error, i add only one value to hull, and when i use largest_contour_index, it does not point to anything. My bad, stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

Because your `hull` collection has 1 element INITIALIZED on index 0 `(new MatOfInt())`, and the rest of the ArrayList holds empty references.
The `Imgproc.convexHull`method is trying to *convert* your contour (MatOfPoint) element to a hull (MatOfInt), but in order to do that, it needs to have it initialized. Specifically, when you're calling `hull.get(largest_contour_index)`, it's getting a null reference, unless your largest_contour_index is 0.

Edit: Agh I see you answered your own question. Nevermind then